# Material Design Lite Layout breaks on second upgradeDom()

Tags: material-design-lite, riot.js

I'm using [Riot.js](http://riotjs.com/) and I have a root element into which I render a different layout for login box and for the actual app. MDL version is 1.0.6.

I wasn't allowed to post images but screenshots can be found [here](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/3614). It's a bit complicated to setup this in codepen, so I won't do it yet.

If I skip the login and call `upgradeAllRegistered()` or `upgradeDom()` after the app is added to dom, everything works as expected.

However, if I first render the login screen, replace it with the app and call `upgradeDom()` again, the layout doesn't work anymore. The header is not at top.

I've inspected the dom using `diff` and it's identical in both cases. It starts like this:

```
<div id="app" riot-tag="app">
  <div class="mdl-layout__container">
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer mdl-layout--fixed-header has-drawer is-upgraded" data-upgraded=",MaterialLayout">
      <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-color--primary mdl-color-text--primary-contrast is-casting-shadow">
        <div class="mdl-layout__drawer-button"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></div>
          <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
            <span class="mdl-layout-title">Home</span>
              ...
```

I don't believe this happens just with riot but with other frameworks too. I guess the the issue is within the `MaterialLayout` which doesn't work correctly if initialized multiple times. The layout is based on the dashboard example.

Any suggestions how to reset the layout? If not possible, I can always do a full refresh after login.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same situation while using Riot.js, and the solution is to reinitialise the MaterialLayout component of MDL. It's done as follows:

```
<div id="app" class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
</div>

var element = document.querySelector('#app:not(.is-upgraded)')
element.MaterialLayout.init();
```

**Note**: reinitialising MaterialLayout on an already upgraded element is an issue, thus have added the check to see if the element has already been upgraded or not.